# Issue running powershell script on Japanese machines, \ turning into ¥

Tags: powershell

Please bear with me with any suggestions/answers given my knowledge of PowerShell is still a work in progress.

So, where I work We have a number of Japanese machines at the company I work for which need enrollment onto Intune. However, the script we are running isn't working on their machines cause the \ symbol turning into a ¥ symbol.

The part of the script that's having issues is:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\HWID\
Install-Script -Name Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo
CD “C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\”
.\Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo.ps1 -OutputFile C:\HWID\AutoPilotHWID.csv
```

So, of course, the simple solution would be to change the language settings to the US temporally, but this, of course, isn't sitting well with management.

Is there anything I can do within my PowerShell script to undercome this issue and ensure it's using the \ symbol as expected?

I've tried a workaround suggested to me and ran the following and the output was it converted it Unicode Decimal: 92

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> CD "C:$(0x005C)Program Files$(0x005C)WindowsPowerShell$(0x005C)Scripts$(0x005C)"

CD : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\92Program Files92WindowsPowerShell92Scripts92' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ CD "C:$(0x005C)Program Files$(0x005C)WindowsPowerShell$(0x005C)Script ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\WINDOWS\syst...hell92Scripts92:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

So I'm open to any other ideas to work around this.

Thanks

Comment: What if you change "\" to "/"?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1167662/139307 might help.

Comment: rokumaru, thank you that did the trick :)

Comment: Alex or @rokumaru, I encourage you to write the workaround up as an answer, but it would also be good to know why it is needed, i.e., what the actual problem was. The linked superuser.com post suggests that it may be a mere _display_problem.

Comment: It is not a display issue. 

The Windows Japanese code page wonderfully (/s) replaces the backslash in position 0x5C with the yen. But according to the research I've done, this only applies visually. Functionally, it should still behave like a backslash.

But it is breaking the script when I try to run it using backslashes. Changing it to forward slash solves the issue.

Comment: `$(0x005c)` is just a needlessly complicated way of writing `92`. `$([char]92)` would properly produce the desired character, but I'm pretty sure this ought to give the same result as a literal ``\``, unless the script's encoding itself is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fix was to use a forward slash instead of a backslash.